# STS Java Spring Boot Project not building

Tags: git, jenkins

I am recently trying to explore Continuous Integration on my personal Desktop.
Whenever trying to build Application from Jenkins, it is not moving after

** C:\ProgramData\Jenkins.jenkins\workspace\spring-jenkinss # timeout=10**

Please advise.
Thanks in anticipation.

```
Started by user Test
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\spring-jenkinss
The recommended git tool is: NONE
using credential 4b951b11-3d40-4ab8-a383-808c6ae95f67
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository https://github.com/Test/TestJenkinss.git
 > D:\Test\Software\Git-2.35.1.2-64-bit.exe init C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\spring-jenkinss # timeout=10
```

Comment: This issue is not related to STS or Java or Spring Boot. The issue is with git cloning. Check the connectivity between Jenkins machine and GitHub.

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam : Thanks for you reply.I am able to access github from the machine on which Jenkins service is now running.What else do I need to test?Please advise.

Comment: Now I am getting error as mentioned :  hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "D:\test\Software\Git-2.35.1.2-64-bit init C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\spring-jenkinss" returned status code -1: